# Rigify: How do add a new Main Property?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, rigify

Rigify's UI supports having certain Main Properties show up in its side panel depending on what bone you have selected. These are defined in the rig_ui.py, starting about line 733.

What exactly would you need to add to the rig_ui.py in order to have it recognize a new property on a new bone in the Rig Main Properties panel?